# symfony 1.4 как создать виртуальное поле для модели

Tags: symfony

Получил в наследство проект на SF 1.4.

Есть кастомная админка, для каждой модели создаются свои формы, отдельные страницы, которые содержат только те поля, которые есть в базовой модели.
Мне нужно на странице листинга (перечня позиций) добавить дополнительную колонку, которая должна содержать значение из другой таблицы (отличной от базовой модели), но эти таблицы можно связать по ключевым полям.

Для наглядности привожу конкретный пример:
есть страница заказов, которая выводит модель/таблицу "order", заказ может быть отправлен какой либо транспортной компанией.
Все номера ТТН я храню в отдельной таблице "order_delivery", здесь же есть поля со статусом отправляемых посылок которые обновляются по крону.
Моя задача на странице перечня заказов вывести поле статуса заказа, значение из табл "order_delivery" для соответствующих заказов

Вопрос как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если связи правильно прописаны, то получить можно как-то так:

```
$order->getOrderDelivery()->getStatus()
```